# Prolog console crashing the moment I run my script

Tags: console, prolog, swi-prolog, xpce

I have being using prolog and have run different programs on the SWI console multiple times but this week I encountered a program where the moment I would run it on the console on my mac as ['Users/......./desktop/tiles']. The console outputs 5 errors before immediately crashing, would anyone be able to tell me why this is happening?

```
jack(x,y).

:- writeln('   ').
:- writeln('>>>>>>>>>> *** Put har3.jpg into the working directory, then give goals ?- d,i. to start. *** <<<<<<<< ').
:- writeln('   ').
:- writeln('       >>    ... reading the COMMENTS in the PROGRAM also helps ... <<   ').
:- writeln('   ').
:- writeln('   ').
cl :-   free(@d),free(@mypic).   %clear, if I may apply a wild surmise to my own naming.
d  :-nl, write('Of course you can use any picture
        as long as it is called har3.jpg ... '), nl,
write('.... and you put it where Prolog can find it.
                  Such as the working_directory... '),nl,nl, d1.
d1 :-              % d for do, I suppose.
     new(@mypic,picture('R. Harmenszoon van Rijn' )),
     send(@mypic, size, size(700,750)), % the default size is too small
     send(@mypic,open),
     new(I,image('har3.jpg')),    % use (local) variable I instead of
                                %         global @i
     new(B,grbitmap(I,point(3,3),size(5,5),point(30,20))),
     send(B,name(harmensz)),  % A rose by any other name... but we may have to
                  % find the chap, so we name him.
     send(@mypic,display( B, point(400,70))).

i :- i(5,7).   % default intialization

i(Mx,My) :- get(@mypic,member(harmensz), Har),   % i for initialize
    get(Har,image,I),
    get(I,size,SI),
    get(SI,width,SIW),
    get(SI,height,SIH),

    DX is floor((SIW-0)/Mx),write(':'),write(DX),
    DY is floor((SIH-0)/My),write(DY),
    new(@d,device),
    send(@mypic,display(@d, point(70,70))),
    make_alltiles( Mx,My,SIW,SIH,DX,DY,I),
    send(Har,displayed(@off)),
          % comment the line above out
      % if you want leave the original jpg as a hint.
    new(Box,box( @d?width, @d?height )),
    send(@d,display,Box),
        make_circles( Box,My,Mx),
    scramble( Mx,My)
    .
scramble(Mx,My) :- scramble( Mx,My,33).
scramble(_,_,0).
scramble(Mx,My,Count) :-
    R is random( Mx+1),L is random( Mx+1),
    U is random( My+1),D is random( My+1),
    rmy(R),lm(L),   um(U),dm(D),
    Count1 is Count-1,
    scramble(Mx,My,Count1).

make_alltiles( Mx,My,SIW,SIH,DX,DY,I) :-
    make_cols( Mx,My,SIW,SIH,DX,DY,I,Mx,My).

make_cols(0,_,_,_,_,_,_,_,_).

make_cols(C,My,SIW,SIH,DX,DY,I,Mx,My) :-
    make_tiles( C,My,SIW,SIH,DX,DY,I,Mx,My),
    C1 is C-1,
      make_cols(C1,My,SIW,SIH,DX,DY,I,Mx,My).

make_tiles(_,0,_,_,_,_,_,_,_).
make_tiles(C,R,SIW,SIH,DX,DY,I,Mx,My) :-
    C0 is C-1, R0 is R-1,
    X is C0*DX, Y is R0*DY,
    new(A,area(X,Y,DX,DY)),
    get(I,clip,A,Itile),
    new(Btile,grbitmap(Itile,point(C0,R0),size(Mx,My),point(DX,DY))),

    send(@d,display( Btile, point(X,Y))),
      make_tiles(C,R0,SIW,SIH,DX,DY,I,Mx,My).

 %----------------------------------------

rmy(Row):- send(@d, for_all, tile, message(@arg1, move_r, Row)).
lm(Row):- send(@d, for_all, tile, message(@arg1, move_l, Row)).

um(Col):- send(@d, for_some, tile, message(@arg1, move_u, Col)).
dm(Col):- send(@d, for_some, tile, message(@arg1, move_d, Col)).


:- pce_begin_class( grbitmap, bitmap,"Bitmap that moves on a grid" ).

variable(grpoint, point, both, "Grid point at which Bitmap is displayed" ).
variable(grmax, size, both, "Number of grid rectangles (= grid points -1)"  ).
variable(grtile, point, both, "Size of the rectangular tiles" ).

initialise(DB, I:image=image, P:grpoint=point, M:grmax=size, T:grtile=point) :->
    send(DB,send_super,initialise, I),  %first we initialise a plain bitmap
    send(DB,grpoint,P),
    send(DB,grmax,M),
    send(DB,grtile,T),
    send(DB,name,tile),
    send(DB,recogniser,move_gesture(left)).

move_r(DB,Row) :-> get(DB,grpoint,P),get(P,y,Py), Py =\= Row.
move_r(DB,Row) :-> get(DB,grpoint,P), get(DB,grmax,M), get(DB,grtile,T),
    get(M,width,Mx),get(P,x,Px),
    X1 is Px+1, Px1 is X1 mod Mx,      %Px -1 for move_l
      send(DB,grpoint,point(Px1,Row)),
    get(T,x,Tx),get(T,y,Ty),
    DisPx is Px1*Tx, DisPy is Row*Ty,
      send(DB,move,point(DisPx,DisPy)).

move_l(DB,Row) :-> get(DB,grpoint,P),get(P,y,Py), Py =\= Row.
move_l(DB,Row) :-> get(DB,grpoint,P), get(DB,grmax,M), get(DB,grtile,T),
    get(M,width,Mx),get(P,x,Px),
    X1 is Px-1+Mx, Px1 is X1 mod Mx,      %Px +1 for move_r
      send(DB,grpoint,point(Px1,Row)),     %
    get(T,x,Tx),get(T,y,Ty),
    DisPx is Px1*Tx, DisPy is Row*Ty,
      send(DB,move,point(DisPx,DisPy)).



move_u(DB,Col) :-> get(DB,grpoint,P),get(P,x,Px), Px =\= Col.
move_u(DB,Col) :-> get(DB,grpoint,P), get(DB,grmax,M), get(DB,grtile,T),
    get(M,height,My),get(P,y,Py),
    Y1 is Py-1+My, Py1 is Y1 mod My,      %Py +1 for move_d
      send(DB,grpoint,point(Col,Py1)),
    get(T,x,Tx),get(T,y,Ty),
    DisPx is Col*Tx, DisPy is Py1*Ty,
      send(DB,move,point(DisPx,DisPy)).

move_d(DB,Col) :-> get(DB,grpoint,P),get(P,x,Px), Px =\= Col.
move_d(DB,Col) :-> get(DB,grpoint,P), get(DB,grmax,M), get(DB,grtile,T),
    get(M,height,My),get(P,y,Py),
    Y1 is Py+1, Py1 is Y1 mod My,      %Py -1 for move_u
      send(DB,grpoint,point(Col,Py1)),
    get(T,x,Tx),get(T,y,Ty),
    DisPx is Col*Tx, DisPy is Py1*Ty,
      send(DB,move,point(DisPx,DisPy)).




:- pce_end_class.

:- pce_begin_class( trcircle, circle,"we design our own button"  ).

variable(func,point,both, "1st: 1,2 for row,column
          and 2nd: number of row or column, 0-based"  ).

initialise(C, Dia:diameter=int, Fun:func=point) :->
    send(C,send_super,initialise, Dia),
    send(C,colour,colour(black)),
    send(C,fill_pattern, colour(yellow)),
    send(C,slot,func,Fun),
    send(C,recogniser, click_gesture(
         left,'',single,
         message(@prolog, fundl, /*@receiver*/C?func?x, /*@receiver*/C?func?y))),

    send(C,recogniser,click_gesture(
         right,'',single,
             message(@prolog, funur, @receiver ?func?x, @receiver ?func?y))).

:- pce_end_class.

fundl(1,Y) :- lm(Y).   % Well, I guess one could rewrite and get rid of these
fundl(2,X) :- um(X).   % four lines
funur(1,Y) :- rmy(Y).
funur(2,X) :- dm(X).

make_circles(Box,R,C) :- make_rcircles( Box,R,C),make_bcircles( Box,R,C).
make_rcircles(Box,R,C) :- make_1rcircle( R,Box,R,C).

make_1rcircle( 0,_,_,_).
make_1rcircle( N,Box,R,C) :- get(Box,area,A),
    get(A,height,Ah),get(A,x,Ax),get(A,y,Ay),get(A,width,Aw),
    DY=floor((Ah)/(2*R)), N0 is N-1, Y is Ay + DY + N0*DY*2,
    X is (Ax)+(Aw)+8,
    new(TRC,trcircle(14,point(1,N0))),
    send(TRC,center,point(X,Y)),
    send(@d,display,TRC),
    make_1rcircle(N0,Box,R,C).

make_bcircles(Box,R,C) :- make_1bcircle( C,Box,R,C).

make_1bcircle(0,_,_,_).
make_1bcircle(N,Box,R,C) :- get(Box,area,A),
    get(A,height,Ah),get(A,x,Ax),get(A,y,Ay),get(A,width,Aw),
    DX=floor((Aw)/(2*C)), N0 is N-1, X is Ax + DX + N0*DX*2,
    Y is (Ay)+(Ah)+8,
    new(TRC,trcircle(14,point(2,N0))),
    send(@d,display,TRC),
    send(TRC,center,point(X,Y)),
    make_1bcircle(N0,Box,R,C).
```

This is my script.

Comment: We need the exact errors reported

Comment: @rajashekar the the errors are only there for less than a second and then the window closes automatically, I cannot take a screenshot nor see what the error is before the window closes

Comment: @niconico : I don't know what shell you're using — `bash`? `zsh`? `csh`? something else? — But try piping `stdout` and `stderr` into a file. I believe this syntax should work across most major shells (but I can't swear to `csh` since I've never used it): `swipl ... 2>&1 | tee my-logfile.txt`. That should capture the output, even if the shell/window crashes.

Answer (score 0):

The errors I see are from references to undefined predicates. Add this as the first line of your file to fix those:

```
:- use_module(library(pce)).
```